# Permission denied after installing Ganache with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm, ganache

I'm using **ubuntu** and installed **node** via **nvm**.

```console
nvm --version   
0.39.1
```

```console
nvm list 

       v16.13.2
->      v17.4.0
default -> v16.13.2 (-> N/A)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v17.4.0) (default)
stable -> 17.4 (-> v17.4.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.9 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.18.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.13.2 (-> N/A)
```

```console
npm --version  
8.3.2
```

I have *$NVM_DIR* configured:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This load>

export PATH="$PATH:/home/helio/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin"
```

I installed Ganache with:
`npm install --global ganache`
and it's under:
`.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/ganache`

But when I run for example:
`ganache --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie`
I get:
`bash: /home/helio/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/ganache: Permission denied`

When I look up for this error the solution always ends up installing `node` via `nvm` so everything will go under `.nvm`.

Can someone help me understand what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've used `sudo` to install something globally before. You probably shouldn't be using `sudo` with `npm` or `yarn`.

I know it sounds extreme, but if you've used `sudo` in order to install npm packages and don't understand the ramifications of doing so (it allows the package author, or any of the authors of dependencies that package relies on to do anything everything they desire with your system; they could install backdoors or even update your bios if they wanted to). You may want to consider formatting your hard drive, resetting your bios, and reinstalling your operating system if you've made a habit of doing this.

Using `sudo` with the global flag (`-g`) also changes your npm folder's permissions, which causes issues like you are seeing above. If you don't want to follow my suggestion to reset your system, npm has an article on how you can try to fix npm's permissions: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally .

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'm pretty sure I didn't use `sudo` to install any package but I will reinstall everything to make sure and state in my question that I did not use it.

Comment: Oh, also... you shouldn't use Node 17 unless you have a reason to do so, and if you don't know if you have a reason to, then you probably don't have a reason to (odd numbered major Node.js releases, like 13, 15, 17... are a bit like Node.js's version of a `beta` release)

Comment: So, I uninstalled ganache then I followed your advice and installed the LTS version of node (16.13.2) and re-installed Ganache globally without using `sudo` and everything is working now. Maybe I used `sudo` in the past or maybe something's wrong with the version of node I was using (17.4.0).. Anyways, thanks for the help!! And great job with Ganache!

Comment: Great to hear! On StackOverflow you should mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.